# Send Mail through dependent plugin

Tags: wordpress

please suggest me, I want create my own plugin that is dependent on another plugin, my requirement is when a another plugin data is get updated for EX. if Insert, Update query is fired in another plugin, then I want to send mail('XYZ plugin data is updated') through my plugin, please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

use class approach for that. like in once class you insert the data and once you success with that then call another class function this would be great idea like

```
$data = insert function();
if($data) {
    mailhelper->mail();
} else {
    data insertion error.
}
```